# SignalR: Access Hub class from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing **.Net Core** web application and want to access IHubContext outside of controller class but I am not able to reference the NotificationHub class.

Here is my solution structure with some marks (red numbers): [Solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ7ty.png)

If I try referencing NotificationHub class from Service project, it always underlines NotificationHub class and Visual Studio offers these suggestions: [Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoFPh.png)

**NotificationHub.cs (in project 1)**

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", user, message);
    }

    public Task SendPrivateMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", message);
    }
}
```

**...Service.cs (in project 2)**

```
private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext; // it uderlines "NotificationHub"

public PDUSwitchService(ILogger<PDUSwitchService> logger, IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _hubContext = hubContext;
}
```

How am I able to access NotificationHub class (in project 1) from Service project (in project 2)?

Comment: Have you added a project reference ?

Comment: I added project reference from 1 to 2 (project 2 is support class, it performs calls to database etc.). I can't add reference from 2 to 1 because it gives me an error: `Adding this project as as reference would cause a circular dependency.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move your hub class to a separate project, otherwise you have a circular dependency (Web project depends on Service and Service depends on Web).
After moving, Web project will reference Hub and Service projects, Service will reference Hub project, so the problem should be solved.